# What does "ongoing" mean in "There is an ongoing investigation"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

What does "ongoing" intends to say? Is it just something that is "in course"?. For example: There is an ongoing investigation.

Is it ongoing because the investigation is happening in this moment? or is it also related to the frequency of the action?

Comment: It has nothing to do with frequency. **ongoing** means "in progress", that is, it is already underway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about translation into Spanish.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Translation is off-topic here - we can help with specific questions about English. It would help us if you explained why the dictionary hasn't helped you understand the meaning of "ongoing". You may want to take the [tour] to learn a little bit more about how this site works.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have edited the title - I think that we may be able to help with the meaning of "ongoing" without explicitly translating it to Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Ongoing [means](https://www.yourdictionary.com/ongoing) "it's happening right now" and also means "it's going to keep happening" (for a while at least):

> There is an **ongoing** debate about whether cell phones should be given to children.
>
> The **ongoing** war led to famine.
>
> Due to the **ongoing** parade, roads will be closed.

It is not related to the frequency of the action. It just means it's happening at the present time.

Answer (score 1):

*Ongoing* can be used to talk about a business process, or other formal or bureaucratic process.

It means that:

- the process would be reported as active,
- and usually implies that actual actions are being taken to bring the process to conclusion.

Comment: Not all things that use the word ongoing come to an end, though. An ongoing debate may never end.

it's correct about investigations but not necessarily about other things that can be ongoing.